# SQL Query for products ordered on regular basis

Tags: sql, time, product

I need to create a query which shows products being sold on regular basis such as daily or monthly.
I have two tables Time and Sales

Sales table has the following columns

- Time ( which relates to the time_key column in time table)
- product key

Time table has the following columns

- Time_key
- Day
- Day_of_the_week
- Month
- Quarter
- Year

This is what I did for finding quarter products

```
Select sales.product, time.quarter, product.product_name 
from sales , time, product 
where time.time_key=sales.time and time.quarter=’1’ and product.product_key=sales.product 
group by time.quarter, sales.product, product.product_name
```

Comment: What is the desired result? What have you tried already?

Comment: I want to show products ordered monthly. I ran a query which shows all the products but not with the months they were bought in

Comment: You might want to consider updating your question with any code examples etc of things that you have already tried, and look at [this guide on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). I don't think you have provided enough background or enough detail to allow people to help you. You also haven't really demonstrated that you have done your own research for a solution before asking the question.

Comment: Ok I have answered another question using this query to find the quarter     Select sales.product, time.quarter, product.product_name 
from sales , time, product 
where time.time_key=sales.time and time.quarter=’1’ and product.product_key=sales.product 
group by time.quarter, sales.product, product.product_name         and I am new to this site I do not know how to use it yet

Comment: The basic problem is there is no understandable question there!